# Show $\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_q\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$ whenever $0<p\leq q\leq \infty$ using log-convexity of $L^p$ norms.

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Assume that the measure space is finite for this to make sense. Also, we know that $L^p$ spaces satisfy log convexity, that is -
$$\|f\|_r \leq \|f\|_p^\theta \|f\|_q^{1-\theta}$$
where $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\theta}{p} +\frac{1-\theta}{q}$.
The text which I am following says 'Indeed this is trivial when $q=\infty$, and the general case then follows by convexity'. I understand that it is true when $q=\infty$, however I am unable to use that it is true for $q=\infty$ for proving the general case. I have found a proof which uses log-convexity and the fact that $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\|f\|_p^p=\mu(\text{supp}f)$. Is there some way that I can do this by using that it is true for $q=\infty$?

Comment: What make you believe the optimal result can be obtain, through this convex inequality ? it is not possible since this inequality seems not to be optimal whereas the original one is optimal

Comment: Shouldn't $f=1$ a.e give equality in the log-convexity inequality? How is it not optimal?

Comment: just take $ r=p$ in your log convex but nothing interesting

Comment: $r=p$ just gives $\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_p$ right? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{q}p>1$  then the map $\phi: x\mapsto x^{\frac{q}p}$ is convex and therefore by Jenssens inequality(which is convexity)  we have

$$\phi\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f|^p d\mu\right)\le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X\phi\circ|f |^pd\mu $$
 that is 
$$\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f|^p d\mu\right)^{q/p}\le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f |^qd\mu $$

that is $$\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_q\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what I want to know is we can use the log- convexity of $L^p$ norms along with using that it is true for $q=\infty$ to show this result.

Comment: @Manan what do you mean by log-convexity?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, for $q\ge p$,
$$
\begin{align}
\|f\|_p
&=\left(\int_X|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&=\left(\int_X|f(x)|^p\cdot1\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&\le\left(\int_X|f(x)|^q\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac1q}
\left(\int_X1^{\frac q{q-p}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac1p-\frac1q}\\[9pt]
&=\|f\|_q\,\mu(X)^{\frac1p-\frac1q}
\end{align}
$$